# Jquery auto focus but copy fails

Tags: jquery

I have a working code where if user type anything it focus on textbox.

But what I want is when the user type Ctrl + C it should let the user copy any text available in website.
Also it should support all the ctrl commands, like Ctrl + A, Ctrl + P, etc

```js
        jQuery('body').keydown(function (e) {
            if ((e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 173 || e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 111) || (e.keyCode >= 185 && e.keyCode <= 193) || (e.keyCode >= 219 && e.keyCode <= 222)) {
                $('#textbx').focus();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
to select and copy text

<br><br><br><br>
<input class="textbx" id="textbx" value="" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to know if `CTRL` is pressed or not.

```
$(body).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = true;

    if ((e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 173 || e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 111) || (e.keyCode >= 185 && e.keyCode <= 193) || (e.keyCode >= 219 && e.keyCode <= 222)) {
        $('#textbx').focus();
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = false;

    if (ctrlDown && e.keyCode == cKey){
       $(body).select();
       document.execCommand("copy");
    }
});
```

Comment: it break the auto focus on any key press :(

Comment: Try removing the `keyup` portion to make sure that is what is doing it.  If it is, move your `focus` if statement to there instead.

Comment: can you please check here: https://jsfiddle.net/p47a3107 both do not work.